# my device is not detecting in Eclipse Android

Tags: android, eclipse

(am a complete newbie)

before, I use windows seven os for running the app on the device and it works. but when I moved to vista it cant work. and when After inserting my device through USB cable to the laptop . the laptop need install cdc abstract contol model. when i install the the device failed. how to fix that?

Comment: question is not clear? Your device is not detecting in eclipse?

Comment: did you enabled  USB DEBUG MODE on your device  ?

Comment: @talhakosen always enabled, because before im running to 7

Comment: yes, finally it works. im go to my computer -> properties and run device manager. there is a ADB interface tree and my computer ADB and i click, i choose driver tab -> update driver. thanks for all answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try to look with command line tool ( adb devices )  - it shall show your connected device.  If it is not there, you will need some weird driver from somewhere (go google for 
it, I use linux and do not need them )

Answer (score 0):

You have to install USB Driver software in your machine and restart the eclipse